# How to delete pushed Docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

```
Image 0dd747e33c96 already pushed, skipping
Image 9ebea32a283d already pushed, skipping
Image 3690474eb5b4 already pushed, skipping
Image cbf4c83202ff already pushed, skipping
Image 09ddd09520af already pushed, skipping
```

How can I remove these images from a **private** docker registry? (it's v1)? I have access to the server.

Why do I want to do that? I am building an image via Jenkins docker plugin and it just does not push changes to the registry. Building on local works.

*I would be happy to forcefully overwrite them too.*

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your images are actually layers of images. While you make changes, it doesn't mean that all layers are changing. And if there hasn't been any change at, docker and the registry are smart enough to not push anything. This is not an issue of old images not being updated on push with new ones, but more like old image layers not being changed as part of your build process.

In v1 there is no way to delete an image. Best option is to update to the newer registry as v2 has been out for a very long time already.

---

The more recent versions of the docker distribution provide an API.

Checkout the docker distribution API docks for deleting an image

https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/ed0b3aebb31a38ba617bb21494de9e914b6e4bed/docs/spec/api.md#deleting-an-image

> Deleting an Image
>
> An image may be deleted from the registry via its name and reference.
>   A delete may be issued with the following request format:
>
> ```
> DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
> ```
>
> For deletes, reference must be
>   a digest or the delete will fail. If the image exists and has been
>   successfully deleted, the following response will be issued:
>
> ```
> 202 Accepted Content-Length: None
> ```
>
> If the image had already been
>   deleted or did not exist, a 404 Not Found response will be issued
>   instead.
>
> Note When deleting a manifest from a registry version 2.3 or later,
>   the following header must be used when HEAD or GET-ing the manifest to
>   obtain the correct digest to delete:
>   Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json

Comment: The big headline indicates the document is about v2, as you can see from my post we are running v1.

Comment: @kev - i edited my post wrongly. Why are you on a downvoting spree? People are trying to help afterall.

Comment: Your post was not an answer to my question before editing. Unfortunately I cannot just upgrade to v2 (would have done that long time ago if possible). It's pretty annoying that this stuff doesn't work as expected and ppl. answering having no clue makes it even worse.

Comment: I just read my answer after so many years, and realized what a peice of crap it was and deleted it right away. This is the correct solution by manojlds. @kev If you don't have V2, there should be way to get rid of some files or something within the v1 server itself, but not sure how exactly, but pretty sure there should be way. Many people suggesting hub docker, which is a public registry, but here you are talking about a private registry, which not many people have or understand, and hence lot of wrong answers and people are even upvoting them!

Answer (score -2):

go to https://hub.docker.com/repositories
clack on tags then you could Determined your image and then you will find up Action
click on it and you will see delete ► that is it ◄